# How to create URL links from strings

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using:

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='internet'>$1</a>");
```

to turn, for example `http://www.example.com` into a clickable link. This works well!

Does anyone know how to expand this expression to capture also `www.example.com` (i.e without `http://`)?

Comment: Start from the beginning. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ash: Seems he wants to convert the strings `http://www.example.com` and `www.example.com` to `<a>` tags.

Comment: yes - am trying to convert http://www.example.com and www.example.com to <a> tags.

Comment: This is nice in principle, but it won't be easy... Depending on your source, you'll probably end up getting a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Add a `( )*` here

```
((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)*
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NBWyr/

Basically zero or more of the items in `()`

Comment: I tried that with `var text = 'http://www.google.com is a cool website, but www.yahoo.com is not.';` and it didn't work properly. More text was highlighted than should have been.

Comment: @styfle. As far as I know, this regex is meant to work on addresses only, not sentences.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Jason I figured it would parse a block of text like a comment on a website, then find and replace links in that block.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
(?<http>(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having problems with using this in a function:

function replaceWWW(text) {
var exp = (?<http>(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)/ig;
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='internet'>$1</a>"); 
}

Maybe I have missed a escape character?